# Android Requires MinSdk <=9

Tags: android, sdk

When I am trying to make a new Google Maps Activity, its grey and I cant click the option. `(New --> Google --> Google Maps Activity (Requires MinSdk >=9)`
I got the same message when I create a new app and try to choose the activity while setting up a new project.

```
C:\Users\Joey\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms
```

Android-23

And when opening the SDK manager in Android Studio I got the following SDK tools.
[image]

Can someone tell me if Im missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your application level `build.gradle` file do you have `minSdkVersion` `9` or greater than `9` like this:

```
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15 //this should be greater than or equal to 9
        targetSdkVersion 23
        //...
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! If was minSdkVersion 8. Did change it in 9! Thx a lot for helping me!